# Invoke function async on AWS Lambda

Tags: javascript, node.js, aws-sdk

I'm trying to invoke a function as async because I don't wan't to wait the response.

I've read the AWS docs and there says to use `InvocationType` as `Event` but it only works if I do a `.promise()`.

*not working version*:

```
lambda.invoke({
  FunctionName: 'rock-function',
  InvocationType: 'Event',
  Payload: JSON.stringify({
    queryStringParameters: {
      id: c.id,
      template: c.csvTemplate
    }
  })
})
```

*working version*:

```
lambda.invoke({
  FunctionName: 'rock-function',
  InvocationType: 'Event',
  Payload: JSON.stringify({
    queryStringParameters: {
      id: c.id,
      template: c.csvTemplate
    }
  })
}).promise()
```

Anyone could me explain why it happens?

Answer (score 4):

[`invoke`](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSJavaScriptSDK/latest/AWS/Lambda.html#invoke-property) returns an [`AWS.Request`](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSJavaScriptSDK/latest/AWS/Request.html) instance, which is not automatically going to perform a request. It's a representation of a request which is not sent until `send()` is invoked.

That's why the latter version works but the former does not. The request is sent when `.promise()` is invoked.

```
// a typical callback implementation might look like this
lambda.invoke({
    FunctionName: 'rock-function',
    InvocationType: 'Event',
    Payload: JSON.stringify({
        queryStringParameters: {
            id: c.id,
            template: c.csvTemplate,
        },
    }),
}, (err, data) => {
    if (err) {
        console.log(err, err.stack);
    } else {
        console.log(data);
    }
});

// ... or you could process the promise() for the same result
lambda.invoke({
    FunctionName: 'rock-function',
    InvocationType: 'Event',
    Payload: JSON.stringify({
        queryStringParameters: {
            id: c.id,
            template: c.csvTemplate,
        },
    }),
}).promise().then(data => {
    console.log(data);
}).catch(function (err) {
    console.error(err);
});
```